# Is a series of GO buttons, at each step of iphone user interaction, easier for user to understand than different title each button?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, mobile, user-behavior, buttons

Anyone see any problem with a series of GO buttons for each step of a mobile diagnostic app?

That is, when user starts iPhone app, user sees titling, a couple of optional config controls,
and a big  GO  button.
User presses GO, view changes, user is asked to do something and then tap another GO button.
This repeats a couple times.
Finally, there's a STOP button shown instead of GO.

This is for an iPhone app that checks performance of our health wearable.

This will only be used by in-house (mostly engineering) personnel, and also executive team including CEO to verify performance of wearable, such as on a golf course.

THEORY...
I want to minimize user having to stop and interpret the meaning of a different button title at each step -- so they just get used to:   GO ... GO ... GO ... GO ... STOP
boom, they're done.

(maybe "DONE" instead of STOP..)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if a user can go a to a previous step, having a "BACK" and "GO" button to navigate through each view doesn't give much insight, but it would be helpful to describe each "view" with a specific name.

That way, you could name each "BACK" button the previous view, and each "GO" to the next view. If you give each view a name and display what category they are currently viewing, users will always know where they were **previously**, where they are **currently**, and what the next step **will be**.

Then after they are all done, make the button describe what they will see when they submitted. (i.e. "VIEW REPORT", "SEND DATA")

*(Also, progress bars are extremely helpful to users to know how far they are along the sequence.)*